# AWS Elastic BeanStalk + Wordpress URL rewrite Issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hey Guys i deployed wordpress with Elastic Bean Stalk ( i have nginx + RDS ) but only wordpress home page working fine but URL rewrite not working. ( wordpress home page working fine & wordpress from NON google friedly URL works fine ) problem is with URL rewrite anyone has any idea how we can solve this OR how we can install APACHE on AWS EBS ( i am using EBS +  RDS + Code Pipeline )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **AWS provides** official whitepapers and guides on how to **properly setup** and run Wordpress on Beanstalk. I put the links to them, since from your question it is not clear if you followed any of them and why they don't work, nor why they are not suited for your use case:

- [Build a WordPress Website Deploy and host a production-ready WordPress website on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-wordpress-website/)
- [Deploying a high-availability WordPress website with an external Amazon RDS database to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html)
- [Deploying WordPress with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf)
- [WordPress: Best Practices on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/wordpress-best-practices-on-aws/)

If your needs are different, updating the question with more details and explanations would be useful to provide more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much detail to go on here but it sounds like you may need to update your NGINX configuration in order to point non-static files to index.php so that WordPress 'process' them accordingly.

If you add this to your `nginx.conf` file (in `/etc/nginx/`) inside the `server{}` block:

```
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Then reboot NGINX and test WordPress URLs to see if it worked:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

If that does the job then you will need to make this change permanent, otherwise as your Elasticbeanstalk environment scales or is re-deployed the change will revert. To do this depends if you are using Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI.

If you are using AL2 then you need to add this change to the `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/` directory of your local development environment and re-deploy, see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

If using the Amazon Linux AMI you will need to create a `.conf` file in the `.ebextensions` folder which implements the change upon deployment, see here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files/